# authentication process , for refresh token and sessions , jwt?

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, backend, refresh-token

express.js login process

when a user logs in with email and password

1. i verify the email amd password (from database)
2. then check if the user has a existing session (if yes i delete it, user can only log in once)
3. i create a new session , with user_id , and a random refresh token (32 digits)
4. then i create a jwt with user_id, session_id and refreshtoken
5. this is saved to cookie and also sent back to user

when user acess any other request ,

1. i get the jwt from cookie , if not in cookie.
2. then i verify token , if verified  , i move to the required endpoint
3. if token is expired i read the token , get the session id and the refresh token from it ,
4. if the refresh token matches in the session id ,i generate a new refresh token and replace it inside session (so if token is expired it automatically is refreshed)
   i generate a new jwt and save it inside cookie , (my refresh token are replaced when they are used once)
5. then i pass it on to the new request
6. if my refresh token does not match , i suspect that someone else had access to the token and then log the user out , and delete his session ,

is this process correct ,

in the above process , if two requests comes in one after the other in quick succession at the same time that the token expires , will the first request pass through since its refresh token matches , but as it goes through the the refresh token will change? will it invalidate the second request that comes in since it might carry the old refresh token and log the user out????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.